# Install R package in Unix

Tags: linux, r

I'm trying to install a package in R in Unix

I used the following :

install.packages("rminer", repos="http://cran.r-project.org", lib="~/R/libs/")

I get the following error

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xgboost’
* removing ‘/net/zmf1/cb/5/mms140130/R/libs/xgboost’
ERROR: dependency ‘xgboost’ is not available for package ‘rminer’
* removing ‘/net/zmf1/cb/5/mms140130/R/libs/rminer’


Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("rminer", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.r-project.org",  :
  installation of package ‘xgboost’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("rminer", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.r-project.org",  :
  installation of package ‘rminer’ had non-zero exit status
```

what can I do to install the "rminer" package in R in Unix

I also tried

```
mkdir ~/R/
mkdir ~/R/libs/
echo 'R_LIBS_USER="~/R/library"' >  $HOME/.Renviron

R CMD INSTALL -l ~/R/libs/ rminer_1.4.2.tar.gz
```

it gave me the following error

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘plotrix’, ‘kknn’, ‘pls’, ‘mda’, ‘randomForest’,  ‘adabag’, ‘party’, ‘Cubist             ’, ‘kernlab’, ‘e1071’, ‘glmnet’, ‘xgboost’ are not available for package ‘rminer’
* removing ‘/net/zmf1/cb/5/mms140130/R/libs/rminer’
```

appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say 'linux', but surely it will be a particular flavour of linux, like debian, ubuntu, red hat etc?

I normally install packages (like R) using a package installer like '[apt/aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt)'.

Check what the package installer for your flavour of linux is called, apt is available on debian/ubuntu systems.

Comment: actually I'm using Unix, not sure what you are mean

Comment: Ok, Unix is in fact a number of operating systems, linux is an 'open source' version of unix, and exists itself in many variants. You can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) that there is one original unix from AT&T, and I can't imagine you're using that? I would recommend that you find out what your unix is, for example 'uname -a' would give you some information.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the answer to my question

Comment: I'm sorry that it is not the answer you're looking for, just trying to help by putting you on a different track. Ultimately you want to install rminer, right? I recommend that you use a package manager instead of compiling from sources.

Comment: what is a package manager?

Answer (score 0):

The installation of **rminer** can't be complete because the compilation of another package **xgboost** fails.

The **xgboost** packages requires a recent and working C++ compiler.
Try run:

```
install.packages("xgboost")
```

and post the error messages. When **xgboost** is installed correctly then **rminer** can probably install easily.